# major product formed in wurtz reaction in the given molecule[ 1,3-dibromo-2,2-di(1-bromomethyl)propane ]

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, ring-strain

[image]

This is the reactant molecule which undergoes wurtz reaction. All possible products are-
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What will be the most favorable in all of these? In my opinion that the last one should not be the one because it forms a three member ring which is quite unstable due to angle strain. Still it is the answer to the question.

**why any other molecule is not the major product?**

Comment: Reactions that can take place within a molecule generally occur faster than those between molecules

Comment: @Waylander And what about angle strain? To what extent we can ignore it's role in determining the product

Comment: According to https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01118a042, it is indeed the last one, spiropentane (approx. 50 % conversion). You can foster the search process knowing your precursor's more common name (pentaerythrityl tetrabromide) and CAS number (3229-00-3).

Comment: @ashank Yes, it is a strained species, but there are very many cyclopropanes known so clearly the strain is not a determining factor.

Comment: @Waylander if we had a molecule (apart from cyclic one) having exceptional stability, can we say that it will be formed more in comparison to the one formed by intramolecular reaction?

Comment: @andselisk That was too complicated  for me. I grasped a few things but most things were beyond my knowledge. btw thanks

Comment: @ashank I don't think you can make a general statement about this. It will be different for each situation.

Comment: @ashank No prob, this was just a published confirmation for the given answer. It doesn't seem authors provide an in-depth explanation as to *why* spiropentane is favored, so your question remains.

Comment: @Waylander I just want to convey that intramolecular reactions are fast, but they might lose in some cases, now that depends .  I believe that we can't really explain some things just by theory if things are happening so close in terms of stability. There are too many factors to look upon.

Comment: Spiropentane is preferred, because it does not contain any bromine atom. If enough sodium is available, all bromine atoms will be transformed into $\ce{NaBr}$, so that the final product must be a hydrocarbon with $5$ atoms, or a polymer.

Comment: @ashank  Exactly so. That is why chemistry remains an experimental science. You cannot predict the outcome of many reactions so you have the run the experiment